# Accumulate media content from multiple requests

Tags: tcp, request, video-streaming, protocols, rtmp

Firstly, I'm not sure if the title is clear enough. I just try to explain what happens to me and what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to detect the direct link of media files (films, videos, etc...) from some website by using 'Firebug' (Firefox), 'Inspector' (Firefox) or other tools in Chrome. I also tried with Wireshark. It's pretty easy for some website because I can see the direct link from the request and by using programs like Quicktime, I can save the file to my local disk. For some other websites, I can see requests for streaming media content. However, the problem is that for the same file, there are many requests. It seems that after each several seconds, they use a different request to load, say 1.5Mb. When I copy one detected link to the address bar, the browser downloads a small file (media type), but the file cannot be played. Following is one example for using multiple requests for a same video:

[image]

My questions are:

- How can they decompose the video content into multiple requests? How can they accumulate the responses? What kind of Protocol used? (From Wireshark, it's TCP stream, but I'm not sure if it correct because I read somewhere that rtmp is common). I watched a video on YouTube about 'rtmpdump' but it isn't applicable in this case (in the attached image)

- Is there any client tool that can help us to accumulate multiple media responses?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is an HLS stream. Look at the start of the playback for a .m3u8 file. This will list the URL for each file. Each file is a small piece of the total video, Usually 2 to 10 seconds. Each segment should be playable on its own assuming there is no DRM. It is deliver over HTTP. Hence the name HTTP-Live-STREAMING

Comment: Thanks for the name of protocol. I can see a request for the playlist, but its response is very short:
    #EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1003481,CODECS="avc1.77.31,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360
chunklist.m3u8?token=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MTQ0MjM4OTI1OCZoYXNoX3ZhbHVlPTI2YmMxZTM2NDAzNjYyNmQ3NTQyZmNmZmRmNWNmMWIxJnZhbGlkX21pbnV0ZXM9MTQ0MCZjaGFubmVsX2lkPXZ0djEtaGQ&did=d13af09df6d23cf4c66034d3b5d7d610d150b2d8.

And each downloaded segment cannot be played.

Comment: This is a nested playlist. An m3u8 inside and m3u8. Download chunklist.m3u8?token=... and look at it. It will contain all the ts files.

Comment: Now I can see "get chunklist" requests. Each "get chunklist" contains 3 links to video segments. I can download segments, but the file with extension ".ts" doesn't play. Do you know how to play a segment? and how to assembly segments together?

Comment: Just concatenate them. VLC will be able to play the result. In fact VLC will play the whole thing if you give it the m3u8.